# How do I keep my finger from sounding another string when bending

Tags: guitar, electric-guitar, note-bending

When doing a one and a half step bend on guitar, or even a whole step, I can't seem to keep my finger from grabbing the other strings and I can hear them. Do I need to set my action differently? I've got them where they should be according to the Jackson specs.